# Passing in a variable into a label vb

Tags: vb.net

I am currently creating a chess game a to save me a large amount of `if` statements I was wondering if there is a way to insert a variable such as `x` into the label below:

```
Label1.Text = "MyRedPawns()"
```

I want it to go in the `( )` similar to what would be used for a `Console.Writeline` statement.

**Edit:**

Here is the code:

```
For x = 1 To 4
  If mouseclicklocation.X >= MyRedPawns(x).getposition.X And mouseclicklocation.X <= MyRedPawns(x).getposition.X + 80 Then
    If mouseclicklocation.Y >= MyRedPawns(x).getposition.Y And mouseclicklocation.Y <= MyRedPawns(x).getposition.Y + 80 Then
      Label1.Text = "MyRedPawns( )"
      Piecefound = True
    End If
  End If
Next x
```

I want the value of `x` which is in the for loop to be passed in to the `label1.text` inside the `()`

Comment: This is not clear at all. What kind of variable is `x`, what do you expect as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Label1.Text = "MyRedPawns(" & x & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. However, i'll give it a try. I guess you want to insert the value of a variable `x` into a `string`. You can use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim pattern = "MyRedPawns({0})"
Dim xVariable As Int32 = 4711
Dim result = String.Format(pattern, xVariable)
```

Result:  `MyRedPawns(4711)`

Have a look at the remarks section of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If we had a variable x = "Hello" to get the text from x into the label we would do:

```
Label1.Text = x
```

I'm not sure what MyRedPawns() actually does or returns so I could be wrong but if it is returning a String and takes a parameter then you should be able to do:

```
Label1.Text = MyRedPawns(x)
```